# creating a lottery that tells you if you've won and how many times(python)

Tags: python

the user must chose one number between 1 and 90, the program creates a 5x5 grid with random numbers in it(from 1 to 90) and tells you if you've won and how many times.
this is what i've come up with:

```
    import random
    numeri=range(1, 90)
    c=0
    while(c<5):
        c=1                     
        while(c<=5):            
            print(random.sample(numeri, k=5),"\t")
            c=c+1               
        c=c+1
        print("")
```

but i can't really wrap my head around on how to make
it check if the input is in the grid...
if you think that the question is out-of-topic, just tell me and i'll take it down.
ty

Comment: Why the need of a grid? Create a list of 25 elements that admits duplicates, then check how many times your number is in the list with `thelist.count(element)`.

Comment: In a grid, just iterate through the rows, and for each row, iterate for the elements, and if the element == the user input, increment the number of times they’ve won

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
user_num = input(“Enter your num: “)
# this assumes the input is a valid integer
user_num = int(user_num)
# create grid
count = 0
for row in grid:
    for lottery_num in row:
        if lottery_num == user_num:
            count += 1
```